# array or strings concatenation in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation

I have the following result of an array_filter:-

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PS59.jpg)

I need to improve the output above: I want to add before "the start" and add after "the end" (with single or compound words, like this):

For example:

```
**$start** = 'de la' ;
**$end** = 'en una';
```

What I need to do to change all output strings, to have this final output:

the following were designed as "$y";

```
**de la** revolución; verticalmente, el tema debe enmarcarse **en una** 
**de la** Revolución francesa están comprometidos **en una**
**de la** obligación humillante de traducir la lengua nacional **en una** 
**de la**s interjecciones, que al igual que nuestros gritos constituy **en una**
**de la**'verdadera filosofía {32}. La lengua universal basada **en una**
```

I have tested no success the following codes:

```
$outputx .= $start + $y + $end;
```

or

```
echo $start . $y . $end ;
```

I need a big help here I'm gonna be really thankfull

Colt

Comment: Smells like a homework

Comment: Please post array here (in your question), not in image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `foreach` statement

```
$start = 'de la';
$end = 'en una';
foreach($your_array as $y){
   echo "$start $y $end ";
}
```

Comment: Its not a good practice to modify prefix/suffix. If its change later, they have to add spaces. I would recommend to modify it in your code like @Alive to Die did. And this will fail, if you make an unit testing because they won't be the same result as its expected due to double spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution for you:

```
//Lets say you have an array containing all the texts
$textList = [];
$prefix   = 'de la';
$suffix   = 'en una';

$sep    = sprintf(' %s %s ', $prefix, $suffix);
$result = sprintf('%s %s %s', $prefix, implode($sep, $textList), $suffix);
```

test: https://eval.in/892350

Comment: Thank you so much. Word fine